# selinux and systemctl start versus service start

Tags: selinux, systemctl

From https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/getting-started-with-selinux_using-selinux  `1.4. SELinux architecture and packages`

> Important: To avoid incorrect SELinux labeling and subsequent problems, ensure that you start services using a systemctl start command.

is doing `systemctl start <service_name>` the same as doing `service <service_name> start` ?  Will doing the later cause selinux labeling problems?

Comment: The `service` command is really a legacy command meant for managing old `/etc/rc.d/init.d` style scripts. You really shouldn't be using it with anything as recent as RHEL8. In most cases it's really just a wrapper for `systemctl`, so the two commands you mention will generally be equivalent.

Comment: @larsks While I agree with you that `/etc/rc.d/init.d` should never be shipped with new installations, I have to deal with several vendors who have not caught up with the times. These vendors also tend to insist that SELinux be disabled (which is against our security policies and which I cannot change) so we often reach an impasse where I have to fix the vendor's install or startup scripts to meet the modern world.